# Cookies with path are not being sent

Tags: typescript, cookies, jwt, nestjs

I am using nestjs , the problem arrises when i set the cookie path as then i will be able to send the refresh jwt token at /refresh route only

```
import { Response, CookieOptions } from 'express';
const cookieOptions: CookieOptions = {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: true,
  maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000,
};
response.cookie('rf-jwt', tokens.access_token, cookieOptions);
```

if i add the path in the cookie options then the cookies are not sent
if there is any other secure settings i need to follow please let me know

that rf-jwt will be sent
its there in the response header as set-cookie:rf-jwt
but not set in the cookies in the application tab

Comment: What path are you adding?

Comment: /refresh so that at only /refresh the rf-jwt is sent and not at other routes

Comment: If you make a request then to the `/refresh` route, do you see the cookie actually sent?

Comment: Actually, I didn't check that, because I thought it must be available as a cookie in the storage, I will check that and let you know. If my api is like xxx:3000/api/
then the path should be /api/auth/refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it just doesn't show in the application tab but it's being stored just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).